# Cover photo of an album not returned

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

First of all this is not a question itself. I have developed an android app to download photos from Facebook.

To get the the cover photo of an album, I made graph api requests with the graph id of the album and with fields id,name,count and picture. My app worked without much problems till 7th August 2013 and on the very day I found that the field picture does not return the cover photo of the album.

I have checked this with graph api explorer also and issue exists. Do anybody have the same problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue now .. unfortunately no answer yet.